# Passing a DOM element to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I want to run a generic javascript function with an element, sometimes multiple elements in the same HTML document.  It seems to me the easiest way is to call the function from inside a DOM element.  OK here's the problem.  "this" refers the window element and I have seen how scope works for functions using "this" but I don't see how to get "this" to refer to an element.

I could do getElementById but I want a fairly generic javascript and not have to come up with unique IDs everytime I want to use it.  getElementsByClasses may be a workaround but it just seems there should be an easier way to do this without relying on id's or classes.

The HTML

```
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id="content">
  <div class="linksbox">
    <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
      <div class="linkicon">
        <img src="asislink.jpg">
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
    </div>
    <script>valignimg();</script>
  </div>

</div>      <!-- End content -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The javascript.  It's dh and ih that I need to pass to the function.

```
function valignimg() {
  dh = /* div element */ 
  ih = /* image (child element) */ 
  topmargin = (dh.offsetHeight - ih.offsetHeight)/2;
  return topmargin;
}
```

Comment: This is what IDs for actually. To use elements in js code

Comment: I reaed the question 3 times, still dont know what you want to achieve... but I will guess. I guess you could use onload="" to run some JS on every element, but that is just ugly. Why not to use classes?

Comment: Do you have jQuery on the page?

Comment: Which of those four `div`s you want `dh` to refer? To `.linkicon`?

Comment: If you're looking for img tags you could use `document.getElementsByTagName` to get them. Then you're script is still in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not calling it from one of the elements (i.e. via event handler), you're going to have to use a selector of some kind, either ID or class as you highlighted, or name or tag name if that can work, or some combination. Somewhere along the way it will need to be specified. In even though you weren't keen on using class, that's likely your best option so I've highlighted it in this first example.

```js
//warning - this event isn't supported on some older browsers like IE8
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  valignAll();
});


function valignimg(dh) {
  //Only added the IDs for this purpose, not using them to select elements so there's no functional requirement for them.
  console.log(dh.id); 

  //This supposes that you know the image tag you want is always the first img element among dh's children.
  ih = dh.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  console.log(ih.alt);
  
  var topmargin = (dh.offsetHeight - ih.offsetHeight) / 2;
  console.log('dh.offsetHeight = ' + dh.offsetHeight);
  console.log('ih.offsetHeight = ' + ih.offsetHeight);
  console.log('topmargin = ' + topmargin);
  ih.style.marginTop = topmargin + "px";
  console.log('ih.style.marginTop = ' + ih.style.marginTop);
}


function valignAll(){
  var linkIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('linkicon');
  for(i = 0;i < linkIcons.length;i++){
    valignimg(linkIcons[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="linksbox">
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon1" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img1" src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon2" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img2" src="http://placehold.it/21x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon3" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img3" src="http://placehold.it/22x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End content -->
</BODY>
```

You can see, although my usage is pretty rudimentary, I've used getElementsByTagName as well, calling from a parent element other than document. The IDs I've added aren't used for locating anything, I'm just using them so that when I log to console you can see which element it really is, the same as with my horrendous misuse of the alt attribute on the images.

If you know that your only image elements on the page are the ones you're acting on, then maybe starting with document.getElementsByTagName('img') is the approach for you, and then get the div with the .parentNode property. This would remove the reliance on classes, but if you add other img tags to the page then you'd need some way to identify from each one whether it's once you want to run your align function against or not. The img tags you want to access have a common ancestor or parent that no other img tags do. I've added another snippet below that shows this. And you could combine these two approaches with a nest loop to get all img tags within multiple divs that all share a class, for example.

```js
//warning - this event isn't supported on some older browsers like IE8
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  valignAll();
});


function valignimg(ih) {
  //Only added the IDs for this purpose, not using them to select elements so there's no functional requirement for them.
  console.log(ih.alt);

  //This supposes that you know the image tag you want is always the first img element among dh's children.
  dh = ih.parentNode;  
  console.log(dh.id); 
  
  var topmargin = (dh.offsetHeight - ih.offsetHeight) / 2;
  console.log('dh.offsetHeight = ' + dh.offsetHeight);
  console.log('ih.offsetHeight = ' + ih.offsetHeight);
  console.log('topmargin = ' + topmargin);
  ih.style.marginTop = topmargin + "px";
  console.log('ih.style.marginTop = ' + ih.style.marginTop);
}


function valignAll(){
  //if they're the only img tags on the page, 
  //document.getElementsByTagName('img'); will work fine.
  //lets assume they aren't.
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('linksbox')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
  //I can grab the comment parent/ancestor by whatever means available, and then grab just its decendants by tag name.
  alert(images);
  for(i = 0;i < images.length;i++){
    valignimg(images[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <div id="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x20">&lt;&lt; Some sort of header logo
    <div class="linksbox">
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon1" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img1" src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon2" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img2" src="http://placehold.it/21x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://www.corponline.org" target="_blank">
        <div id="icon3" class="linkicon">
          <img alt="img3" src="http://placehold.it/22x20">
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="linkblurb">
        <h2>National</h2>
        <p>Description of link</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  Sponsor Logos or Site Certs in the footer
  <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
  <!-- End content -->
</BODY>
```

Comment: Exactly, without mind reading this is an unanswerable question, that's why it should be closed and not be answered. All answers without further information are pure speculation ; ).

Comment: What I want to do is vertically center an image in a div.  Yes I know there might be ways to do this specific task but I want to do it with javascript.  I would prefer to not use getElementById because suppose I have 20 images I want to use - all require a unique ID.  It was while working on this project that I realized that I didn't know how to get "this" to refer to the element making the function call which in this case is the div containing the image.

Comment: I don't want the function to run on an event.  It should run automatically from the HTML.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with shortly. If not class, then tagName is probably the next most viable option.

Comment: @SaintCad - I've added some. If you're deadset on avoiding relying on classes, the second example does that. However it still requires some knowledge of the DOM structure. In this case I'm using that DOMContentLoaded event rather than jamming the call into a script tag at the bottom of the page. It's roughly the same idea as using $(document).ready in Jquery, minus a lot of stuff Jquery previously did for cross-browser and legacy browser safety (not certain the 2.x versions still need to, based on their support lists).